# Alternative for copy.com

Tags: sync

The start of the week, I had an email from Copy.com saying that they were closing their service in May.

What are peple going to use and is there anything as good as Copy.com for size allowance and Ubuntu friendly?

Really do not want to use Dropbox with only 2GB allowance and not interested in trying to get more from it.

Comment: Define Ubuntu-friendly ? Your question so far doesn't seem related to Ubuntu at all. You're asking about service suggestion, which is not the purpose of this site

Comment: What functionality do you want the service to perform?

Comment: Ubuntu friendly, something that works with Ubuntu and has client, unlike google drive. Come on man, just asking for advise here so lets not get high and mighty.

Comment: Just want to keep my files in the cloud and for all my systems to be able to sync with it. Copy was good for this. Shame it is going.

Comment: Sorry, but "high and mighty?" You may want to take a look at the help center. The rules are clearly defined there, and @Serg is correct. On a different note, [MEGA](http://mega.nz) has 50GB for free, and a sync client for pretty much every distro of Linux you can imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem that the Mega option is a good option with the 50 gb free and most of all a nice and friendly Ubuntu client. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found pCLoud to be a great alternative to Copy, as they offer a switch from Copy to pCLoud in two easy steps. Find out more about it [here](https://www.pcloud.com/copy-gift/?gclid=CNer5-67g8sCFUI_GwodphUNcA). They will also give you free storage and a months free encryption. Hope this was helpful. :)